# Warning Integer operation result is out of range

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation

```
f = (double *) malloc(2500000000*sizeof(double));
```

when I try to allocate memory for this large size, it gives a warning "Integer operation result is out of range".

Comment: If the argument is too large for its type, why would you think such an allocation request would work?  Does your computer really have space for 2.5 *billion* `double`s?

Comment: @ScottHunter Well I would only have 4GB left, but yes ;)

Comment: @ScottHunter At 8 bytes per `double`, that's a bit under 20 GB, well within reach of current systems.  The code is likely just being run on a 32-bit system.

Comment: You should see if you can compile your program in 64-bit mode. `2500000000*sizeof(double)` is simply too big for 32 bits.

Comment: Also notable, various older versions of the usual mainstream OS:s could only address 32 bits. It doesn't make sense to allocate more memory than what the address bus of your system can handle, regardless of the amount of physcial memory present.

Comment: Under rare circumstances, `calloc(2500000000, sizeof(double))` may work even though `malloc(2500000000*sizeof(double))` does not.  (This is probably not one of those circumstances, though.)

Answer (score 1):

Per C 2018 5.2.4, “Environmental limits,” sometimes things just get too big for a C implementation to handle. When the compiler tells you an integer operation result is too big, that means the numbers involved are bigger than the compiler supports, at least in this situation.

It cannot represent the result in the integer formats it uses, and, even if it could, it almost certainly could not allocate that much memory for you. This will not work, and you must another way to solve whatever problem you are working on, one that uses less memory.

Alternatively, you could switch to using a C implementation that supports larger sizes, but using 2½ billion `double` objects, likely 20 billion bytes, is likely not to work as well as you would like even in implementations that support it. There are problems that benefit from holding such an amount of data in memory, but programs that work with this amount of data generally need to be well designed with consideration for performance characteristics of computing hardware and software, such as respect for the amount of physical memory available, properties of the memory cache, and other workload on the system.

Answer (score 1):

For many years I've had the sensation that computers are just too fast to be comprehended.  And these days the amount of memory they have is just too big to be comprehended, too.

On the one hand, yes, `2500000000*sizeof(double)` is a stupidly big number.  By yesterday's standards, nobody ought to be able to malloc that much memory.

But on the other hand, I just typed this little program into the four year old, consumer-grade laptop sitting in my lap:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    double *f = malloc(2500000000*sizeof(double));
    unsigned i;
    for(i = 0; i < 2500000000; i++)
        f[i] = 1 + i/1000000000.;
    printf("%f %f %f\n", f[0], f[2500000000/2], f[2500000000-1]);
}
```

The program compiled and ran without error, printing `1.000000 2.250000 3.500000` as expected.

(To be sure, the default compiler for this machine compiles for the x86_64 model.  This code could never work in 32-bit mode.  And it took almost 40 seconds to run, in part because I "only" have 16 gig of memory on this laptop, so the poor beleaguered OS had to dip in to virtual memory.)

But although the program did work, it's definitely on the edge of reasonableness.  If you've got a truly big, hard problem to solve, sometimes brute force and lots of memory is the way to solve it.  On the other hand, though, sometimes a line like

```
double *f = malloc(2500000000*sizeof(double));
```

is a pretty good indication that something hasn't been thought through properly.